# pandas infer_freq returns None

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas frame where the index is a `DateTimeIndex` and I am trying to infer its frequency and it is coming up as None.

```
df.index

DatetimeIndex(['2020-08-24 00:00:00', '2020-08-24 00:01:00',
               '2020-08-24 00:02:00', '2020-08-24 00:03:00',
               '2020-08-24 00:04:00', '2020-08-24 00:05:00',
               '2020-08-24 00:06:00', '2020-08-24 00:07:00',
               '2020-08-24 00:08:00', '2020-08-24 00:09:00',
               ...
               '2021-08-22 23:51:00', '2021-08-22 23:52:00',
               '2021-08-22 23:53:00', '2021-08-22 23:54:00',
               '2021-08-22 23:55:00', '2021-08-22 23:56:00',
               '2021-08-22 23:57:00', '2021-08-22 23:58:00',
               '2021-08-22 23:59:00', '2021-08-23 00:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='timestamp', length=307668, freq=None
```

As you can see the data is coming at a 1 minute frequency but when I do something like:

```
pd.infer_freq(df.index)  # returns None
```

Is there some other way to figure out the input frequency? Is there a method that would be robust to some missing data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`freq` is already `None` in this case, so you should try:

```
>>> pd.to_timedelta(np.diff(df.index).min())
Timedelta('0 days 00:01:00')
>>>
```

Or just:

```
>>> np.diff(df.index).min()
numpy.timedelta64(60000000000,'ns')
```